# Django: pull from database instead of push to database

Tags: database, django

I've inherited a v 1.0 Django/Python intranet site.

Django normally pushes from the Django code into the database.  For say, table definitions (DDL).

Db architects associated with the project have a new database design that they want me to hook up to the site.

That is, I need somehow to pull the DDL defintions from out of the db and into Django code.  E.g. some way to generate a new class from a table.

I know a lot of python but much less Django.  Any ideas on how this might be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Django can work with pre-existing DB's.  Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/legacy-databases/) out.

Basically, the command you need to pull models from the DB is `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

Comment: Ah! - looks very good.  I've wondered what inspectdb was for.  Let me try it out at work tmw and I'll post my results.  I'd guess your answer is correct but would prefer to confirm that after I've tried it.  Thank you.